# Tomcat support on WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I am JavaScript developer, and currently working on project where Tomcat server is used.

I am familiar with IntelliJ idea but recently read about another JetBrains product specially for web-development - WebStorm. I've found some cool features in WebStorm(especially related to AngularJS autocompletion) but it seems that there is no Tomcat server support and I have to build server side of project into *.war-file and run it manually through terminal each time.

So is there any Tomcat/Java support in WebStorm?
(Or I should continue to use IntelliJ idea and forget about WebStorm and its cool functionality =) )

Comment: I can't answer the "does WebStorm support Tomcat" portion of your question since I do not use it... but I'm curious as to what "cool functionality" in WebStorm you would lose by changing to IntelliJ IDEA. WebStorm is a subset of IntelliJ IDEA **Ultimate**. (You do not mention if you've used ultimate or community.) Anything in WebStorm is also in IDEA. (The main difference is in project setup.) While it is not bundled into IDEA by default, the exact same AngularJS plug-in that WebStorm uses is available to IDEA _Ultimate_. Just install it from the JetBrains plug-in repository in Settings.

Comment: **Simply speaking:** WebStorm is targeted for JavaScript/HTML/CSS (and similar languages/technologies, e.g. SASS/LESS/Dart/NodeJS etc) -- it does NOT support any of the Java-specific stuff. Need Java and related technologies -- keep using IntelliJ -- any "missing" functionality (available in WebStorm but not in IntelliJ IDEA **Ultimate**) can be installed via plugin manually (as mentioned above).

Comment: Ok, I've got it. 
Thanks for response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one thing.

- First start your apache tomcat server with startup.bat/startup.sh. (Suppose your project directory name is "AngularJSTest" in WebStorm.)
- Right click on that > Refactor > Move .
- Give the path to **webapps** directory of Apache tomcat.

So from now on whatever changes you make in the project from **WebStorm**,  it will get reflected in the webapps directory. You can access it from the link http://localhost:8080/AngularJSTest/yourHtml.html.

Comment: This is horrible advice. Throwing the baby out with the bath water.

You likely want to keep your web project within your git repo/project folder and not directly in the tomcat webapp folder. You also don't want a cleaned tomcat to wipe your project directory from webapps.